# Joint probability from marginal and relation between variables

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, marginal-probability, copula

I would like to know whether it is possible to obtain the joint density function $p(x,y)$ if I know one marginal, which is Gaussian $p(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \exp(-\frac{1}{2} (\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma})^2)$ and the relation between variables $y = \frac{1}{(1+x^{2})}$.

I know that virtually one can always obtain the marginal probability density function $p(y)$ if $p(x)$ and the dependence between variables $y=f(x)$ are known, via the distribution function technique. However I don't know how one would construct from there, if possible, the joint density.

I am aware that this is doable numerically, but I am looking for a method to obtain an analytical expression. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no joint density for $x$ and $y$. The range of $(x,y)$ lies in a  set of measure zero so the density function does not exist.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. If I obtain a pdf for $p(y)$, which is technically possible (am I right?), then why would not exist a joint pdf such that $p(y)=\int dx p(x,y)$ and $p(x)=\int dy p(x,y)$?

Comment: I made a mistake in the relation between $x$ and $y$, now it is solved.